# What do these markings on the side of my screen represent?

Tags: pokemon-go

Occasionally, usually when I'm stuck watching the Pokeball of sadness during a server desync, I'll see some odd marks on the side of the screen that don't appear to do anything. What are they for?

[image]

Comment: I've seen those once before, but they did not do anything when I touched them. Time to do some investigation

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The arrows on the side are **indicators to turn you into the direction of the Pokemon**.

Whilst it is used only in **Augmented Reality** (AR) mode, it appears a glitch has occurred in your screenshot and the indicator stayed even after you switched out of AR mode.

Comment: Actually, they didn't appear until it was clear that I was desynced from the server. I never use AR.

Comment: I can confirm that I have never had these come up in AR mode.

Comment: @Timelord64 Try entering the catch screen **in AR mode**, aim at the Pokemon, then turn yourself 180 degrees.

Comment: @Timelord64 they are indeed standard in AR mode when you're not looking at the pokemon.

Comment: I never use AR mode and I get this bug sometimes as well.